# React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child in React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I installed `react-router-dom` 4.1.1 and keep receiving the following error when trying to render my components:

> Uncaught Error: `React.Children.only` expected to receive a single React element child.

Here's my `app.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from './components/Nav/nav';
import Search from './components/Search/search';
import Favorites from './components/Favorites/favorites';

const App = () => (
 <Router>
    <div className="app">
      <Nav />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Search}/>
      <Route path="/favorites" component={Favorites}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```

And here is `nav.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav = () => (
    <ul className="nav">
        <li><NavLink exact to="/" activeClassname="active">Search</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/favorites" activeClassname="active">Favorites</NavLink></li>
    </ul>
);

export default Nav;
```

When I remove `<Nav />` from `app.js` it renders, but I don't see what's wrong with the `nav.jsx` file.

Answer (score 8):

You're, for some odd reason, aliasing `BrowserRouter` as `NavLink` instead of just importing `NavLink`:

```
import { BrowserRouter as NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Get rid of that and import directly as a name:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Because `BrowserRouter` expects one *React element* child, not text, the error is thrown.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! it's because the tutorials I was looking had everything in one component so they wrote `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link }` and I just copy/pasted into a separate component. I didn't realize it was an issue. THANK YOU!

Comment: @fafafariba Yep, I wouldn't recommend just following a tutorial, go through it and understand what's happening. `BrowserRouter as Router` is giving an alias to `BrowserRouter` for ease of use. If the answer did help, consider upvoting and accepting!